# Using a JWT token from an OAuth response in a Sails backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, sails.js, passport.js

I'm developing a SPA. I'm doing user authentication through a front-end OAuth authentication library ([office-js-helpers](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers#authentication)). The library opens a popup and the user authenticates, the dialog receives a JWT from the authentication response. Returns the response to the main app and then closes.

I would like to use the JWT from the authentication step to create a session for this user with my API backend. **Is this realistic, or should I create my own JWT from the OAuth JWT?**

I'm using `Sails 1.0`, and I should probably use `passport.js`.

I've looked at some boilerplate and even a tut or three, but everything's using Sails ^0.11. It looks to me like the app structure has changed in 1.0, especially the config.

**Can anyone point me to an updated tutorial or outline a best-practice in my scenario?**

Comment: If your sails backend is providing an API, you should probably not go for sessions? I am using a policy with native jsonwebtoken package. In order to use the JWT for your application, you must be able to identify the user based on the JWT contents (You can check them here: https://jwt.io/)

Comment: @Alex2php my question doesn't mention sessions. I'm asking whether using a JWT generated by another service (say Twitter) should be used as the JWT in my API.

Comment: How could a JWT coming from Twitter could be used as a JWT for your API? Usually you want to authenticate some user, but only Twitter does know the secret of the token? So you could never validate that JWT because you don't know their secret?

Comment: What do you mean by the "secret of the token"? If it's a properly formatted JWT, I should be able to decode the claims from the JWT, right?

Comment: Decode, but not verify the signature. So i could send you a token with user "admin@yourapp.com" and you would log me in. I also don't get which information from a third-party token could be useful authenticate users in your app.